# Oracle Dynamic functions and parameter inputs

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi there's this oracle Procedure:

```
SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE(pTableName in VARCHAR2, pFieldName in VARCHAR2,pFieldValue in VARCHAR2,pFieldType in VARCHAR2)
```

What I would like to know is that what is the fieldtype parameter?

I mean I could

```
queryString := 'DELETE FROM' ||pTableName|| 'WHERE pFieldName = pFieldValue' ;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString USING pFieldName, pFieldValue;
```

right? What am I missing here? Can anyone Help? Thanks!

Comment: there're no spaces after `from` and before `where`. it can be issue when you execute the script. then... `pFieldName` you cannot use it this way.

finally it should be smth like `queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' ||pTableName|| ' WHERE '||pFieldName ||' = :pFieldValue' ;`

Comment: what about the fieldtype parameter? where Do I use it?

Answer (score 3):

The table name can't be a parameter, so you've got to substitute it in as a string. That's just like your example, except you need to put spaces around it as @are noted:

```
queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' || pTableName || ' WHERE...
                           ^ space here         ^ and here
```

The column name can't be a parameter either.

The field value you're substituting *is* a parameter, so it needs (1) a name and (2) a colon in front of it. I'll name it `thing` here so the name will be obviously different than the proc's `pFieldValue` parameter:

```
queryString := 'DELETE FROM ' || pTableName || ' WHERE ' || pFieldName || ' = :thing';
                                                                              ^ parameter
```

The `USING` part of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is for providing parameter values, period. The query has one parameter, so the `USING` supplies one value:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryString USING pFieldValue;
```

The first parameter (`thing`) is given the value of `pFieldValue`.

---

One more thing: Many (including me) think a generic "delete a row" procedure is bad practice. Instead of a compiler-checked statement like this in your code...

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myField = pFieldValue;
```

... you have something not checkable like this - if it's wrong it'll fail at runtime:

```
SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE('myTable', 'myField', 'badidea');
```

And what if you have to do this?

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myValue BETWEEN 10 AND 12;
```

Do you extend the `SP_DELETE_FROM_TABLE` procedure, or write another one? This procedure is a good exercise, but please think twice before using it in a real application.

That said, I get that sometimes you *have* to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for operations like this (for example if the table is accessed via a DB link). Just use it wisely :)

Comment: Thank you! what about the fieldType parameter? Where do I use it?
There is tablename,fieldname,fieldvalue and fieldtype as parameter

Comment: I can't tell how it's supposed to fit in there. Maybe it defines the data type of the column in your `WHERE` clause? For the most part you'd be OK without using it - for example, if the column is negative and `pFieldValue` is the string `'123'` Oracle will cast for you. If the column is date then Oracle will cast only if (1) the string is in formatted as specified in your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session setting or (2) it's a valid ANSI date string - for example the ANSI date string for today (December 24, 2015) is `DATE '2015-12-24'`. The word `DATE` is part of the string.